# Python GTK File Save Dialog, How Can I create "Close Without Saving" ResponseType

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

some times when we need more `ResponseType` for dialogs of our programs. for example, when the user close the file editor, editor shows up dialog to get user choice: "cancel", "close without saving" "save" But "save" and "close without saving" does not exist in `Gtk.ResponseType` so how can I create new response type for this. can this problem fixed with another way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gtk.ResponseType` its a small set of predefined values. These are negative values while positive values (including zero) are left for application developers to use them as needed. From the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/enums.html#Gtk.ResponseType):

> Predefined values for use as response ids in Gtk.Dialog.add_button().
>   All predefined values are negative; GTK+ leaves values of 0 or greater
>   for application-defined response ids.

So, when you add buttons to the dialog, instead of using the predefined Gtk.ResponseType, you can use your own set of response values.

Lets take [this example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#example) from the [python-gtk3 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and add a third option with our own response type value:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK, "OPTION 3", 1))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)

        label = Gtk.Label("This is a dialog to display additional information")

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(label)
        self.show_all()

class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        self.set_border_width(6)

        button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("The OK button was clicked")
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("The Cancel button was clicked")
        elif response == 1:
            print("OPTION 3 was clicked")

        dialog.destroy()

win = DialogWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**What was done?**

We added a third button with label **OPTION 3** which has a response id value of `1`:

```
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK, "OPTION 3", 1))
```

Then, when handling the response, we can check for that response id value and do something different:

```
        ...
            print("The Cancel button was clicked")
        elif response == 1:
            print("OPTION 3 was clicked")
        ...
```

You can create your own enumerated set of positive response values and use them as needed (including zero). Good luck.

**EDIT**:

In glade, when using buttons, you can set the value of the `response_id` as an integer. It's located in the general settings tab of the widget.

Comment: @Nomad your welcome. I'm preparing an answer to your other question. a couple of minutes...